# ApexChart: Dunot chart ir not showing labels

Tags: reactjs, charts, apexcharts, donut-chart

I'm having a problem with donut charts in ApexCharts in my React App.

I have an API that returns to me a JSON and I pass this JSON data to some charts. The chart it's showing correct data, but the label isn't showing anything.

If I change something in the ChartComponent, for example, change the 'fontSize' from 15 to 10 the values ​​of the labels are shown, but when rendering the screen, they disappear and return to 0.

[see here how the graphs are appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Esc.png)

[see here how the graphs are when I change the 'fontSize'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4has.png)

**App()**

```
export default function App() {
  const referenceDate = new Date();
  const currentYear = referenceDate.getFullYear();
  const currentMonth = referenceDate.getMonth() + 1;
  const currentMonthName = referenceDate.toLocaleString("default", {
    month: "long",
  });

  const [month, setMonth] = useState(currentMonthName);
  const [monthId, setMonthId] = useState(currentMonth);
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fillData() {
      if (month) {
        await getData(currentYear, monthId).then((response) =>
          setApiData(response)
        );
      }
    }
    fillData();
  }, [monthId]);
  
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const selectedMonth = e.target.value;
    const selectedMonthId = Months[e.target.value].id;
    setMonth(selectedMonth);
    setMonthId(selectedMonthId);
  };

  return (
    <>
        <div className={styles.chartGroup}>
          <ChartCard title="Business Unit Head" value={apiData ? apiData['first'] : 0}></ChartCard>
          <ChartCard title="Financial" value={apiData ? apiData['second'] : 0}></ChartCard>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.chartGroup}>
          <ChartCard title="Commercial And Pipeline [LATAM]" value={apiData ? apiData['third'] : 0}></ChartCard>
          <ChartCard title="Commercial And Pipeline [NAM]" value={apiData ? apiData['fourth'] : 0}></ChartCard>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.chartGroup}>
          <ChartCard title="HR And Recuitment" value={apiData ? apiData['fifth'] : 0}></ChartCard>
          <ChartCard title="Delivery" value={apiData ? apiData['sixth] : 0}></ChartCard>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

const getData = async (year, month) => (await axiosInstance.get(`/homeChart/${year}/${month}`)).data;

async function generateChartData(data) {
  if (data) {
    return data;
  } else {
    console.log("no data");
  }
}
```

**ChartComponent**

```
export default function ChartCard(props) {
  let progressValue = 0;
  let lapseValue = 0;
  const data = props.value;

  progressValue = data;
  lapseValue = 100 - data;

  const options = {
        colors: ["#0ead69", "#e71d36"],
        labels: ["Progress", "Lapse"],
        title: {
        text: props.title,
        align: "center",
        style: {
            fontSize: "15px",
            fontWeight: "normal",
            textDecoration: "underline",
        },
        },
        stroke: {
        width: 0,
        },
        legend: {
        show: false,
        },
        dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                expandOnClick: true,
                donut: {
                    background: "white",
                    labels: {
                        show: true,
                        total: {
                            show: true,
                            fontSize: "15",
                            fontWeight: 10,
                            formatter: function () {
                                return data + "%";
                            },
                        },
                        name: {
                            show: false,
                        },
                        value: {
                            show: true,
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    };

  const series = [progressValue, lapseValue];

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.ChartDiv}>
        <Chart
          data={data}
          type="donut"
          width="100%"
          height={140}
          series={series}
          options={options}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

**JSON return**

```
{
  "first": 4,
  "second": 24,
  "third": 2.5,
  "forth": 9.5,
  "fifth": 22,
  "sixth": 2
}
```

Comment: tag "chart.js" is wrong because the question is not related to chart.js

Comment: I'm sorry, I removed that